# Kaminari: pagination for custom model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

I have a custom model (not mapping by any tables under database). This custom model is just the result of union many other table's data. I want to use kaminari for paginate this.

for example:

```
def index
   @custom_models = find_all_items # result is an array
   render
end
```

And then i paginate those items on view:

```
  = paginate @custom_models
```

When I run this, I meet exception:

> undefined method `total_pages' for Array:0x007fb4dde63c70

My question is: how can I use Kaminari for custom model file.

**@Edit**
I can use Kaminari now, just use this line:

```
  @custom_models = Kaminari.paginate_array(@custom_models)
                  .page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
```

But now I meet problem: because this is custom model, I'm using custom query. I use raw sql query and paginate by myself using `offset` and `limit` keyword.

For example I return 25 records, and default of Kaminari is displaying 25 records each pages so I can only see 1 page. I can make query for returning total necessary records (for example 1000 records) but I don't know how to make Kaminari understand this and show me enough pages.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, I presume that `fetch_all_items`.is an array.

You could insert pagination at the controller, though this means that database will load the entire collection and then filter the results, using the array pagination method.

```
@custom_models =  Kaminari.paginate_array(fetch_all_items).page(params[:page])
```

But I think the best way is to control the offset/limit (pagination) within your model. To show you how to do that,  it would be helpful to have the code that produces `fetch_all_items`.

You can find more in [Kaminari wiki page](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki)

**update - hacky!!!**

So, now we are looking at a different thing. Not 100% certain this will be enough, but this should be the way to go, if you want to go radical and paginate in the model:

In your model, you should have something like this (which you will have, of course, to adjust to your needs):

```
def fetch_all_items(page, per_page)
    offset = page*per_page
    items = SomeSqlMethod("select .... offset #{offset}, limit #{per_page}") # your sql statement
    total_rows = SomeSqlMethod("select count(..) ....") # to get the total number of records
    total_pages = (total_rows.to_f / per_page).ceil # to get the total pages
    items.class.module_eval { 
        attr_accessor :total_pages, :current_page
    } # to add some variables to make Kaminari happy
    items.total_pages = total_pages
    items.current_page = page
    items # to return this
end
```

In your controller, then, you should have:

```
@custom_model = fetch_all_items(params[:page].to_i, params[:per_page].to_i) # cast to integer to avoid injections and misfunctions
```

Apart from `:total_pages, :current_page`, Kaminari might also want some other variables, like `next_page`, `prev_page`, I don't know. Use the same block, `items.class.module_eval`, to inject them.

Comment: I have tried your option. but I meet exception on view file named: `undefined method 'total_pages' for #Array:0x007fb4daca5288`. About pagination, I paginate on query by myself (using offset and limit keyword).

Comment: If you paginate in the model, then probably you need to also calculate number of pages manually. Please, updates your question with more details, in terms of code, on model and controller level

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look. thanks

Comment: Yaiks... This is indeed hacky... I've posted an updated answer, which I am not very proud of :)

Comment: thanks. it works :D I see it's nice :D  sometime we must find a work around solution :D thanks so much :D